# How to insert a link in Pages which allow me to redirect user to specific sections in the document?

Tags: pages, url

This is the part of my document:

[image]

I would like to add links for line:

```
More info under points 3, 4 and 5.
```

I mean the same points as it is linked in **Table of contents**:

[image]

When I try to add link, there is no option for header or section...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no default jumping points, i.e. bookmarks, for any type of header or section in Pages. You need to first create a bookmark for that point in your document so that you can create a link to it.

To create a bookmark for a header or a section:

1. Go to its beginning.
2. Click on the Document icon on the top right.
3. Click the Bookmarks tab.
4. Click Add Bookmark.

You can now add a link to that point in your document by using the newly created bookmark. See the "[Add bookmarks and link to them in Pages on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/pages/bookmarks-and-links-tanc1c8eb17e/12.2/mac/1.0)" Apple support webpage for more.

You can also create a bookmark through the Insert->Bookmark menu option or simply by pressing <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> +<kbd>B</kbd> after moving to that point in the document.

P.S. Beware of adding a lot of links to bookmarks in a large Pages document, i.e. one with for example 50-60 pages or more. For some reason, Pages slows down noticeably whenever I try to add a link to a bookmark in such a document. The only workaround I could find is to restart Pages after adding a link to a bookmark in such a document. I have encountered this problem in pretty much all versions of Pages since 2018 and with numerous documents. Pages and the document returns to normal once a link to a bookmark is added in such a document and then restarted but adding a link to a bookmark becomes a hassle.

Comment: Thank you. It works;)